# Variable rampUp with Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I try to make an injection with a variety of "breaks" and "atOnceUsers".
I didn't found a nice solution on the documentation for that.

My approach was to create a function called "getNextNumber()" with a local counter, to increase the number of "atOnceUsers", but the function was only called once at the beginning.

Any ideas?

My code:

```
class TestCombinationGetFiles extends Simulation {
    var counter: Int =1 

    def getNextNumber():Int = {
      counter+= 1
      return counter
    }     

  val Get20Files = scenario("get20Files")
   .feed(UuidFeeder.feeder)
   .exec(WebAuth.AuthenticateUser)
   .pause(30)
   .exec(WebCloudContent.GoToTestFolder20)

 val Get10Files = scenario("get10Files").feed(UuidFeeder.feeder)
  .exec(WebAuth.AuthenticateUser)
  .pause(15)
  .exec(WebCloudContent.GoToTestFolder10)

 val loadFolder20TestRamp =            
  scenario("loadFolder20TestRamp").exec(WebAuthSwisscom.AuthenticateUser,             
   WebCloudContentSwisscom.GoToTestFolder20)    

 setUp(Get20Files.inject(
    splitUsers(36) into( 
        atOnceUsers(getNextNumber())) 
        separatedBy(30 seconds)) 

        /* messy Code with correct functionality
        atOnceUsers(1),
        nothingFor(30 seconds),
        atOnceUsers(2),
        nothingFor(30 seconds),
        atOnceUsers(3),
        nothingFor(30 seconds),
        atOnceUsers(4),
        nothingFor(30 seconds),
        atOnceUsers(5),
        nothingFor(30 seconds),
        atOnceUsers(6),
        nothingFor(30 seconds),
        atOnceUsers(7),
        nothingFor(30 seconds),
        atOnceUsers(8),
        nothingFor(30 seconds))
        */
    ,
    Get10Files.inject(
        splitUsers(16) into( 
           atOnceUsers(1)) 
           separatedBy(15 seconds)) 
   ).protocols(WebSetUp.httpProtocol)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've discovered a missing feature in Gatling! I'm going to develop this a bit more and submit a pull request to the Gatling team to (hopefully) get it into the project, but in the meantime, you can get the functionality you desire by providing your own custom `InjectionStep` implementation - just paste this at the top of your `Simulation` file:

```
import io.gatling.core.controller.inject._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

case class AtOnceIncrementalInjection(users: Int) extends InjectionStep {
  require(users > 0, "The number of users must be a strictly positive value")
  var count = users

  override def chain(chained: Iterator[FiniteDuration]): Iterator[FiniteDuration] = {
    val currentUsers = count
    count += 1
    Iterator.continually(0 milliseconds).take(currentUsers) ++ chained 
  }
}

def atOnceIncrementalUsers(initialUsers:Int) = AtOnceIncrementalInjection(initialUsers)
```

This is basically what you tried to do with `atOnceUsers`, but the key difference is the counting is **within** the `chain` method, which will get the incrementing behaviour you wanted because `chain` will be called *each time* Gatling decides it's time to send some requests.

Now you can just use the helper function in the same way you used `atOnceUsers`:

```
splitUsers(36) into( 
    atOnceIncrementalUsers(1)) 
    separatedBy(30 seconds))
```